# Visual Studio Debug Memory1 Window Hex to Dec Mouse Hover Not Working

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am following a C++ tutorial and using the Memory1 window to look at what is stored in my array.
The numbers are in hex and when the instructor hovers his mouse over the hex number a pop up shows what that converts to in decimal. eg. he hovers over the hex 16 in the memory window and a popup says 0x16 = 22.
I do not get a popup when I hover my mouse over the number. Is this an option I need to turn on or what? I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the instructor has some add-on installed. There is no such pop up functionality in Memory window that I know of (apart from address numbers in the leftmost column), but there is in code window when you hover over a variable.

Alternative is to change all hex numbers to decimal in Memory window. Right-click on Memory window and select "Signed Display" (or "Unsigned Display").

Comment: I will try the "signed/unsigned method". It would be great if I could get the hover functionality working though. Thanks for the reply.